# CocoaPods 'Invalid Podfile'. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue

Tags: cocoapods

Here is my Podfile

```ruby
 platform :ios, '6.0'
 pod 'RestKit', '0.21.0’, :inhibit_warnings => true
 pod 'MBProgressHUD’, ‘0.8’
 pod 'Reachability', '3.1.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
 pod 'SDWebImage', '3.4'
 pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.12'
```

Error I am getting in terminal is like

```
      Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/User/Desktop/UserFolder/Projects/hott- 
      ios/Podfile:3: syntax   
      error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
      pod 'MBProgressHUD’, ‘~>0.8’, :inhibit_warnings => true
                 ^. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you single quote marks. I count three wrong quote marks.

Your podfile should look like this (note the syntax highlighting here on StackOverflow):

```ruby
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'RestKit', '0.21.0', :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '0.8'
pod 'Reachability', '3.1.1', :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'SDWebImage', '3.4'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '3.12'
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, you should accept the answer. This helps me and other people with the same problem.